# Using MongoDB with R – how to query and return only nested objects as a data frame?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongolite

I'm using the `mongolite` MongoDB client for R to maintain a huge collection in which a typical document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5b2171ebf128c8989d0d047f",
    "thread": "hellothread",
    "posts": [
        {
            "author": "John",
            "post": "Hello world!"
        },
        {
            "author": "Nigel",
            "post": "Hello!"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In this example, the document represents a single forum thread with some attributes which contains an array of posts with different attributes.

I'm looking for a way to get all posts from a given thread or all available threads (documents) which match certain conditions, e.g. the author is John, and return it either as an array of objects representing individual posts or just an array of strings ("Hello world!").

The output using `mongolite` in R would thus be a data frame such as:

```
author    post             thread
"John"    "Hello world!"   "hellothread"
"Nigel"   "Hello!"         "hellothread"
```

Another example would be to count all posts made by a single author and return this number, or a table containing the number of posts by each unique user.

Again, in R:

```
author     number.of.posts
"John"                   1
"Nigel"                  1
```

I've found a couple of ways but they all return the whole document rather than the nested sub-documents or specific values.

Could you please at least point me in the right direction? Is this approach even sensible? Is there a better approach? I need to use a database like this because the data needs to be accessible by multiple clients.

So far I've opted for a very inefficient option of storing the thread-level attributes inside the post objects.